# Styling a submit button on a Custom Form

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to apply a style to a submit button on a custom form and I am able to successfully apply custom views to all the fields, 
but I am unable to create a custom view for the Submit button.

How do I create a custom view for the submit button?

See at http://ponycon.nyc/contact-us

Comment: Why isn't CSS sufficient to obtain the results you want?

Comment: I have a few divs I'd like to wrap around it for a particular effect.

Comment: I'd suggest that styling should not require you to change the HTML, for good separation of concerns, but if you must, use shape tracing to find what is the closest shape around that button, and what alternate you can introduce.

Comment: That was the first place I attempted to go to. I can't seem to identify it through shape tracing.

Comment: What do you mean? What happened when you tried?

Comment: I doesn't generate a shape of its own. If I click on it, it identifies as zone:content and has the same shape-id number in the code

Comment: And there's nothing under that zone?